# SQL - Is the time complexity for foreign keys O(1)?

Tags: sql, rdbms

Let's say I have this kind of data for example:

```
User:
-id
-name

Comment:
-id
-user id (FK)
-content
```

So when I'm querying the DB to find the user who is related to a comment, does it go through all the rows in Users until it finds a user with the correct id (O(n))?
Or is it indexed like some sort of a hash table, and the DB knows immediately where to find the user (O(1))?

**UPDATE:**
OK obviously I need to rephrase: Is it **possible** to make this O(1) with proper indexing?

Comment: SQL is a specification.  The answer to your question can and probably will vary between each implementation.  Query optimizers use indexes to accelerate column matching when they are available.

Comment: Time complexity is used to measure the efficiency of an algorithm. Since you don't have the source code used in the DBMS, and the implementation varies among them, it's impossible to apply a big O measure of it's efficiency. If you use indexes appropriately, you can usually ask the DBMS to provide you information about the efficiency using EXPLAIN PLAN or its equivalent in your DBMS.

Comment: You'll need to specify which rdbms you're asking about. Indexes are usually implemented with B-trees which means O(log n), although it [looks like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133190.aspx) SQL Server in-memory tables can have hash-table indexes. There may be other implementations that use them too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because that is the complexity for lookup by a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) index.

The topic is (relational) [query optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization) (which could just as well be called query implementation). Online besides textbooks and slides you can read documentation from specific products, which will involve things like indexes and query plans.

SQL is a language, and its implementation depends on the DBMS. Even indexes have no guaranteed standard behaviour other than the constraint aspects PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE.